# Elements are reading out of array of strings, but can't be compared

Tags: c++, arrays, unix

I'm coding a simple custom shell in UNIX and I want to retrieve a specific command string from an array of commands that I loaded in from an external file. I know that my array successfully loaded the commands as all 7 of them are printing out, so I know they are there. However, when I enter in, say, 'mypwd' as input to be retrieved from the array, I get nothing back.

What I've done is I hard coded in the string I want to be read

```
if(command.compare("mypwd") == 0)
```

and

```
if(command.compare(0,5,"mypwd") == 0)
```

the program recognizes and executes my command, but when I try to call if from where it is stored in the array,

```
if(command.compare(command_array[0]) == 0)
```

and i've also tried

`if(command.substr(0, 5).compare(command_array[0]) == 0)`

my else statement error gets thrown.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

// global variables
string username;
string password;
string command_array[7];

int COUNT = 0;
void mypwd();
void build_command();

int main()
{
  int i=0,opcode=0;
  int pid=0, status=0, background=0;
  string command, parameters[3];
  build_command();

  int numberOfElements = COUNT;
  cout << "........................\n" << endl;
  cout << "List of commands loaded.\n" << endl;
  cout << "........................\n" << endl;

  //Print all commands.
  for(int c = 0; c < numberOfElements; c++)
  {
      cout << command_array[c] << endl;
  }

  //Enter command you want to run
  cout << "\Enter command: ";
  cin >> command;

  //Get the command.
  if(command.compare(command_array[0]) == 0)
  {
     cout << "You've read the " << command << " command!";
  }else
  {
     cout << "Command not read." << endl;
  } 
      return 0;
 }

 void build_command()
 {
   ifstream COMMANDFILE;
   string GETCOMMAND;
   COMMANDFILE.open("commands.txt");
   if(COMMANDFILE.is_open())
   {
       while(getline(COMMANDFILE, GETCOMMAND))
       {
          command_array[COUNT] = GETCOMMAND;
          COUNT++;
       }
    }

    COMMANDFILE.close();
 }

 void mypwd()
 {
   ofstream TO_CHANGE;
   TO_CHANGE.open("users.txt");
   if(TO_CHANGE.is_open())
   {
        cout << "Enter new password:";
        cin >> password;
        TO_CHANGE << username << ":" << password;
        TO_CHANGE.close();
   }

 }
```

The output that is currently happening is

```
mypwd
mycopy
myps 
mydf 
mysearch 
myhistory
mylogout

Enter command: mypwd
"Command not read."
```

The only other thing I could come up to solving this problem is maybe loading them into a string of vectors and having them compared that way using the std::vector library or possibly using strtok() but at this point, I'm mostly curious as to what I'm doing wrong in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing my problem by changing my comparison line to

```
if(command == command_array[0].substr(0,5))
```

instead of

```
if(command.compare(command_array[0]) == 0)
```

by setting the substr at the end returned the substring of the element at index [0] and thereby stripping off the extra whitespace in the string. It's not the optimal solution, but it solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The only possibility is that there's whitespace at the end of your commands. Can you change:

```
cout << command_array[c] << endl;
```

For

```
cout << command_array[c] << " " << command_array[c].size() << endl;
```

One you confirm there's extra characters, then you'll have to think about stripping the extra whitespace.

Comment: Here is a view able version of output. https://imgur.com/a/gbwrEha
Is it possible that the format of my external file may have something to do with the extra character?

Comment: Yup...it is my external file. I'll have to reformat it and account for the extra white spaces. Thank you so much! It was driving me crazy because my syntax and logic seemed sound and I was so confused as to why I was getting errors.